# Which time travel story first showed the destruction of Pompeii?

Tags: time-travel, history-of

I’ve encountered the destruction of Pompeii a lot in time travel genre. Some examples which are on top of my head:

- In the episode *Fires of Pompeii* (2008) of Doctor Who, destruction of Pompeii was shown.
- In the S01E02 of Loki (2021), destruction of Pompeii was shown.
- Legends of Tomorrow has also shown destruction of Pompeii.

Which time travel story first showed the destruction of Pompeii?

Comment: I was gonna answer with E. Nesbit's 1906 [*The Story of the Amulet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_the_Amulet), but then remembered that that is a time travel story briefly featuring the destruction of Atlantis via volcano...

Comment: @Lexible Actually, lots of stories have taken inspiration from the destruction of Pompeii. In the beginning of *Star Trek Into Darkness*, a volcano was going to wipe out a primitive alien civilization, but Enterprise crew saved them by going against their orders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have no idea if this is the first, but it's the earliest one I found.

**1944:** "Stuart Taylor in Weird Stories of the Supernatural" by Curt Davis on pp. 27–31 of *Jumbo Comics* No. 65, July 1944, available at the [Digital Comic Museum](https://digitalcomicmuseum.com/preview/index.php?did=17496&page=28).

> THIS, CHILDREN, IF I SET MY DIALS RIGHT, IS POMPEII. . IN THE YEAR 79 A. D.
>
> [. . .]
>
> THE FAMOUS ERUPTION IS ABOUT READY, I JUDGE . . WON'T BE A HEALTHY SPOT TO STAY. LET'S FIND A SAFE PLACE TO WATCH . . .